# Apache nutch in distributed mode not going to crawl from web

Tags: java, hadoop, solr, nutch

I am using apache nutch 2.3, hadoop 1.2.1 (3 datanodes), hbase 0.94, solr 4.8. In order to run apache nutch is distributed mode. I do follwoing steps

1. go to runtime/deploy directory
2. copied apache-nutch-2.3.jar to deploy directory
3. Run this command **runtime/deploy/bin/crawl urls/ hbase_table http://solrHost:8983/solr 1**

where hbase_table is the name of hbase table where nutch will store data.
After command starts, Mapreduce jobs starts for each phbase i.e. inject, generate, fetech,dedup,sorlrindex. All these mapreduce jobs finished with out any error. But When I check from HDFS, there was no data in hbase_table. Where is the problem in configuration. Unfortunately, Apache nutch in distributed mode guide is not completely available (according to my search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In distributed mode of apache nutch, you have to check the logs of your tasktracker. Details of documents crawled should be there and not in mapreduce log. Its url will be like (if your are using default configuration)

`http://data-node-ip:50060/logs/hadoop-{user-name}-tasktracker-{machine-name}.log`

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same issue, but with somewhat newer versions of softwares. see this post [Nutch Solr dataimport handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290214/nutch-solr-dataimport-handler)

As a workaround you can count records in hbase by opening hbase shell and run these commands

```
> list (this will make sure the table is getting created.)
> count 'hbase_table' (this will give you records in it.)
```

alternatively rather then running all commands as a batch, try running them individually.
otherwise you can paste the log files.

Comment: I am using hive with hbase. By using time stamp info, I was able to now that there is no new data crawled. So its not a count problem